# Get order details by user id mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get order detail (`user name`, `shipment method`, `line_items(products)`) I write this query but I don't get the result.

```
select * from orders o
inner join user u on o.user_id=u.id
inner join shipment_method sm on o.shipment_method_id=sm.id
right join line_items l on l.order_id = o.id 
where u.id=11;
```

I have tried some queries but I'm stuck I don't know where.

**Order Table**

```
 id
 shipment_method_id
 user_id
```

**line_items Table**

```
id
order_id
product_id
```

Comment: Use inner join at place of right. Query is ok

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for however that 'right join' is very suspicious

Comment: It might help to include the structure and relevant data from all involved tables.

Comment: i use the inner join but no result, empty table

Comment: can you share sample table contents?

Comment: this query `select * from orders o
inner join user u on o.user_id=u.id
inner join shipment_method sm on o.shipment_method_id=sm.id
inner join line_items l on l.order_id = o.id


where u.id = 11` is working it fetching some records but when i add this line `inner join  products p on l.product_id=p.id` all the records gone table become empty

Comment: That suggests you don't have any matching rows in the products table. We can't see your source data or foreign key definitions so we don't know if your join code is logical or not, or whether you have any relevant records in that table or not